# Не до конца понимаю, что не дописал в коде, чтобы он работал

Tags: javascript, html, webbrowser, elementtree

Данный код должен писать количество элементов во вложенном списке в элементе, в котором они есть

```html
<ul>
        <li>Животные [9]</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Млекопитающие [4]</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Коровы</li>
                <li>Ослы</li>
                <li>Собаки</li>
                <li>Тигры</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Другие [3]</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Змеи</li>
                    <li>Птицы</li>
                    <li>Ящерицы</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li>Рыбы [5]</li>
        <ul>
            <ul><li>Аквариумные [2]</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Гуппи</li>
                    <li>Скалярии</li>
                </ul>
            <ul><li>Морские [1]</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Морская форель</li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

Выше показан потенциальный результат

```
let ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul')
for (var variable in ul) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(variable)) {
        if (ul.firstElementChild(variable)) {
            document.createElement('li')
            ul.innerHTML = ul.length
            ul.append('ul')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for(let li of lis){
  if(li.querySelector('li')){
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = `[${li.querySelectorAll('li').length}]`;
    li.insertBefore(span,li.querySelector('ul'));
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Животные</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Млекопитающие</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Коровы</span></li>
          <li><span>Ослы</span></li>
          <li><span>Собаки</span></li>
          <li><span>Тигры</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Другие</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Змеи</span></li>
          <li><span>Птицы</span></li>
          <li><span>Ящерицы</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Рыбы</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Аквариумные</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Гуппи</span></li>
          <li><span>Скалярии</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Морские</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Морская форель</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul')
uls.forEach(ul => ul.innerHTML = ul.children.length);
```

```html
<ul><li/><li/><li/></ul>
<ul><li/><li/></ul>
```

Comment: Только тут получается, что количество будет записано в ul, а не в li